# Can't login in bitnami wordpress debian virtual machine using virtual box

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, bitnami

I imported the bitnami wordpress debian vm to virtual box and when I type the user and the password it returns this error "Login incorrect". As I can't take a screenshot of the vm, Here's a picture that I took with my phone of the screen: [image: photo]

I already tried to use the virtual box's keyboard to login but the error continues